# Missing character in csv file in Google Sheets for Android

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

In my Ruby on Rails app I'm exporting data to csv, one of my header looks like this:

```
We’ve included a link to a helpful video.
```

When I open it on my computer it looks good, but when I open it in Google Sheets for Android it looks like this:

[image]

This is how my CSV export configuration looks like:

```
CSV.open(file_name, 'wb', encoding: 'utf-8') do |csv|
  csv << column_names

  csv << data
end
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Once it looks good in local, ruby part is unrelated. Blame _Google Sheets for Android_.

Comment: that is not a standard apostrophe it is a unicode right single quote (`\u2019`) not sure how you want to handle that